# How do modern browsers deflate .tar.gz files?

Tags: compression, tar, gzip

Assuming the server is set up correctly, modern browsers are able to automatically decompress .gzip files when they are downloaded. Is the same true for a .tar.gz file?

For example, say you have an HTML5 game with a lot of assets. It would make sense to compress the assets (game models, sound, etc.) into a single .tar file, and then (I assume) compress it again into a .gzip file. Will anything special need to be done on the client side to unpack them? Or is there a better approach to compressing assets on the server, making my question as-is sort of moot?

Comment: Is this programming related? Maybe stackoverflow would be better. Or if web servers then serverfault.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah I wasn't too sure which site to ask it on. I'm not looking for a coding solution, I'm just trying to understand *if* I'll need to come up with a coding solution. But I first am just wondering if I can store assets on the server in a single compressed .tar.gz folder.

Comment: Did you try it? What happens?

Comment: Not yet; I don't have access my server at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The short answer is, the browser doesn't.

Most web servers can transparently `gzip` the data being sent to your browser to save on transmission time, but `gzip` is just a compression algorithm. `tar`, on the other hand, is a format used for batching *files* together into a single archive.

The longer answer is that it's the interplay between two different HTTP headers: [`Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) and [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

When you hit a webpage that uses `gzip`, you're receiving a `Content-Type` of `text/html` with a `Content-Encoding` of `gzip`. The browser knows how to handle `text/html`, and so it transparently uncompresses the response and renders it on your screen.

When you download a `.gz` or a `tar`  file, you're receiving something with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-gzip` (or `x-tar` or `x-tar-gz`), which prompts the browser to treat the data as a file download, rather than trying to do anything with it on its own.

There's no such thing as a `Content-Encoding` of `tar`, since that header [is only ever used to advertise a type of compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) - so sending a `.tar.gz` file to a browser with `gzip` encoding would be pointless and wasteful. The data is already compressed.